# Passing directory path as parameter in R

Tags: r

I have a simple function in R that runs summary() via lapply() on many CSVs from one directory that I specify. The function is shown below:

```
#   id -- the file name (i.e. 001.csv) so ID == 001. 
#   directory -- location of the CSV files (not my working directory)
#   summarize -- boolean val if summary of the CSV to be output to console. 
getMonitor <- function(id, dir, summarize = FALSE) 
{
    fl <- list.files(dir, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = FALSE)

    fdl <- lapply(fl, read.csv)

    dataSummary <- lapply(fdl, summary)

    if(summarize == TRUE)
    { dataSummary[[id]] }
}
```

When I try to specify the directory and then pass it as a parameter to the function like so:

```
dir <- "C:\\Users\\ST\\My Documents\\R\\specdata"
funcVar <-  getMonitor("001", dir, FALSE)
```

I receive the error:

**Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection. In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '001.csv': No such file or directory**

Yet when I run the code below on its own:

```
fl <- list.files("C:\\Users\\ST\\My Documents\\R\\specdata", 
                  pattern = "*.csv", 
                  full.names = FALSE)
fl[1]
```

It find the directory I'm pointing to and **fl[1]** correctly outputs **[1] "001.csv"** which is the first file listed.

My question is what am I doing wrong when trying to pass this path variable as a parameter to my function. Is R incapable of handling a parameter this way? Is there something I'm just completely missing? I've tried searching around and am familiar with other programming languages so, frankly, I feel kind of stupid/defeated for getting stuck on this right now.

Comment: Place a `browser()` statement just before you read the csv file, and check the contents of `fl`.

Comment: what you're supplying to the `list.files` `pattern` argument isn't what you think it is. The correct pattern would be `'\\.csv$'`. What you have now says "match zero or more of the empty character, followed by any character and the letters csv," which would match a lot more than just files ending in '.csv'. Where this pattern would be what you think it means is with `Sys.glob`. For example, you could do `Sys.glob(file.path(dir, '*.csv'))`.

Comment: Why does this same question appear over and over? If you do a search for `r` questions and "getmonitor" you will find FIVE questions in the last week!

Comment: @rrs I tried doing searches for solutions before posting! My apologies if I didn't see those posts and created a duplicate.

Comment: It makes me wonder if this is a homework assignment.

Comment: @rrs it's not a homework assignment. I am doing some programming assignments from a Coursera online course to try and pick up R quickly for my job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're passing `fl[1]` directly to `read.csv` with the qualifying path.  If, instead, you use `full.names=TRUE` you'll get the full path and your `read.csv` step will work properly.  However, you'll have to do a little munge to make your `if` statement function again.

You could also expand on your `lapply` function to paste the directory and file name together:

```
fdl <- lapply(fl, function(x) read.csv(paste(dir, x, sep='\\')))
```

Or create this pasted full path in a separate line:

```
fl.qualified <- paste(dir, fl, sep='\\')
fdl <- lapply(fl.qualified, read.csv)
```

When you do the `paste` step, if you want to be really explicit, I would encourage a `regex` to make sure you don't have someone passing a directory with a trailing slash:

```
fl.qualified <- paste(gsub('\\\\$', '', dir), f1, sep='\')
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: full.names = TRUE worked for me though I want to toy around with your other solutions just so I become more knowledgeable about this. Thank you!

Comment: You are right though I will have to adjust the if statement now. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I am trying to read multiple csv files in a directory using  lapply, the way you explained works fine with 1 csv for me but once I try the following code, I am getting an error of " Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection " any thought how I can fix it? Below is my code:  ` pred <- function(m, dir, input1, input2, input3, output){
  
fl <- list.files(dir, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = FALSE)
fdl <- lapply(fl, function(x) read.csv(paste(dir, x, sep='\\')))

d1 <- read.csv(input1, header = TRUE)
d2 <- read.csv(input2, header = TRUE)
d3 <- read.csv(input3, header = TRUE)`