# File picking using pattern in R

Tags: r

I have a directory which is having multiple files which starts with 001.csv, 002.csv and so on. I want to pick those files in a function for which I pass as an argument to the function. 
For ex.

```
myFiles<-function(x=1:30){
// I should pick only those files which starts with 001.csv till 030.csv.
}
```

I tried using pattern matching but I am not sure how to make pattern matching using another variable which consists of vectors. I even tried using paste function so as to paste the full file path but it was giving me file name as 1.csv and not 001.csv

```
tt<-function(dirname,type,nums=1:30){
filenames<-list.files(dirname)
c<-nums
myVector<-0
for(i in 1:length(c)){
myVector[i]<-paste(dirname,"/",c[i],".csv",sep="")
#print(myVector[i])
}
```

}

Comment: Not the same coursera assignment question again ... see if these help  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508305/passing-directory-path-as-parameter-in-r) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216454/how-to-read-multiple-csv-files-by-creating-function)

Answer (score 0):

One way you are able to get the correct names is to pad the start of the numbers with 0s using `formatC` e.g.

```
paste0(formatC(seq(1:30), width = 3, format = "d", flag = "0"), ".csv")
```

Comment: Or more succinctly `sprintf('d%0.3d.csv',1:30)`

Comment: The leading `d` is a typo, right? Good point though.

Comment: I think so too, but they would still `grep` out

Comment: @RichardScriven a typo indeed `sprintf('%0.3d.csv',1:30)` it is

Comment: @mnel Thanks a lot. Actually I am new to R and getting stuck in very basic problems. Your solution works completely fine with my requirement.